# 8thWall BabylonJS Demo "Tap to place" gap

Tags: javascript, babylonjs, 8thwall-web

There is a bug on the BabylonJS Demo "Tap to place": there's a gap between 2D screen picked point and 3D position on the ground.

I tried with scene.pickWithRay(...): same problem.

Maybe a problem with the xrCameraBehavior...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is related to some changes made to our XRExtras package for Release 12 to improve visual quality on Android phones.  To resolve, try setting the "adaptToDeviceRatio" to true when creating your BABYLON.Engine

Example:

```
engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true, { stencil: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true }, true)
```

(added the final "true" param)